# How to use api token in header php

Tags: php, http-headers, access-token

I am working on a project and I don't know how to use API using token. 
I have token but

Site URL:-  https://example.com/api
This info is given on site:

> To identify yourself you should include the following data on the
> beginning of your requests (header):
>
> Header = Authorization Value = Token token=**YOUR ACCESS TOKEN**

How do I receive and send data from API using PHP?

Comment: can you paste your php code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
$crl = curl_init("https://example.com/api");

$header = array();
$header[] = 'Authorization: Value=Token token=<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>';

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
$rest = curl_exec($crl);

curl_close($crl);

print_r($rest);
```

Comment: i am getting this error using above code

http://image.prntscr.com/image/6d03e0c5e2a64116892b515df4dd80c9.png